# How to fix it with \pstextpath and \pscharpath?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{article}
\usepackage{pst-text,amsmath,pst-eucl,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid]

\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{30pt}
\pstextpath[c](0,1.5ex){\psarcn[linestyle=none](3,0){5cm}{135}{45}}
{\RM Welcom to \LaTeX}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question 1: How to show letter "A" of LaTeX clearly?

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

When I replace

```
 \pstextpath[c](0,1.5ex){\psarcn[linestyle=none](3,0){5cm}{135}{45}}{\RM Welcom to \LaTeX}
```

by

```
 \pstextpath[c](0,1.5ex){\psarcn[linestyle=none](3,0){5cm}{135}{45}}{\pscharpath{\RM Welcom to \LaTeX}}
```

It produces

[image]

Question:

How to its result like first result (of course question 1 has already been solved )?

Comment: I always share useful things to others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a problem with the definition of `\La`. Use:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{article}
\usepackage{pst-text}   
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{30pt}
\DeclareFixedFont{\rm}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{20pt}   
\def\La{L\kern-.23em\setbox0\hbox{T}\vbox to\ht0{%
    \hbox{\rm A\kern-.23em}\vss}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,3)(8,6)
    \pstextpath[c](0,1.5ex){\psarcn[linestyle=none](3,0){5cm}{135}{45}}%
    {\RM Welcome to \La\TeX}%
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(8,2)
    \pscharpath{\RM Welcome to \La\TeX}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the `pst-text.tex` from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pst-text/
and the `pst-text.pro` from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/dvips/pst-text/
you can write outlines text on a circle:

```
\begin{pspicture}(10,10)
\psCircleText[fontsize=6.5mm,radius=4cm](5,5){All is Fun with the typesetting system TeX}%
\psCircleText[fillcolor=blue!40,fontsize=1cm,font=Helvetica](5,5){All is Fun within the World}%
\pscircle[linecolor=red](5,5){4cm}\pscircle[linecolor=blue](5,5){2cm}
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

All files will be uploaded to CTAN as soon as mpossible.

Comment: Help me with second question.

Comment: maybe later today ...

Comment: there is a problem with outline fonts and `\pstextpath` which I cannot fix. Maybe later ...

Comment: Thank you very much. Can it be used with arc?

Comment: no, only with a circle. But you can control the length of the arc with `fontsize` and `radius`

Comment: `\usepackage{pst-text}
\psCircleText[fontsize=6.5mm,radius=4cm](5,5){Welcome to LaTeX}`  for a `pspicture` area of `(10,10)`

Comment: Hi Herbert, I forgot asking you, the problem of \La, we still use \def\La{L\kern-.23em\setbox0\hbox{T}\vbox to\ht0{\hbox{\rm A\kern-.23em}\vss}} as solution!

Comment: Yes, that's another problem and will be fixed in the future ...

Comment: With \psCircleText[fontsize=4.5mm,radius=3cm,fillcolor=black!0,font=Time-Roman](5,5){Welcome to LaTeX}, I loaded it normally but I feel it seems not as bold as \DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{30pt}  \pscharpath{\RM Welcome to LaTeX}. How to get it for \psCircleText?

Comment: use `font=Times-Bold`

Comment: Get same result! My idea is " border ".

Comment: any problem in trying `linewidth=2pt` ??

Comment: \psCircleText[fontsize=4.5mm,radius=3cm,fillcolor=black!0,linewidth=.5pt,font=Time-Roman](5,5){Welcome to LaTeX} is loaded successfully.